# How to reference properties of a class from within a callback

Tags: javascript

Given the following class:

```
class TimerFunk {
    constructor(someObject){
        this.a = 1
        this.someObject = someObject
    }
    funk(){
        console.log(this.a)
        if(this.a > 2){
            return
        }
        this.a++
        this.someObject.execCallback(this.funk)
    }
}
```

When the following commands are executed:

```
t = new TimerFunk({execCallback:function(callback){callback()}})
t.funk()
```

it is intended that the property `TimerFunk.a` is logged to the console until `this.a>2`. However instead the loop only executes once:

```
VM2097:9 1
VM2097:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined
    at funk (<anonymous>:9:25)
    at Object.execCallback (<anonymous>:5:13)
    at TimerFunk.funk (<anonymous>:13:25)
    at <anonymous>:1:3
```

From debugging I have figured out that this is because on the first loop `this` represents the object `t` however, on the 2nd loop `this` represents `someObject`.

Is there any way I can fix this and allow me to access class properties from within the executed callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback is called without the `TimerFunk` instance `t` as the `this` object:

```
function(callback){callback()}}
```

A solution is to bind the `this` object of the callback to the `TimerFunk` instance:

```
funk() {
  ...
  this.someObject.execCallback(this.funk.bind(this));
}
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly pass `t` as the `this` object via `callback.call(t)`:

```
t = new TimerFunk({execCallback:function(callback){callback.call(t)}});
```

Comment: Intuitively I would assume that this.funk.bind(this) wouldn't return funk. Very glad this functionality exists though as I wanted to avoid passing t as an argument if possible! Thanks!